# Is there multiple match doable with any pattern matching function

Tags: regex, r

Actually i was looking for if there is multiple pattern matching with   `grepl()`, `sub()` and so on say something like `grepl(...multiple=TRUE)`. I have a list of files and want to check if multiple extension are existing in the files. For a single extension i use `grepl("*.cel$",lst)` where `lst` is list of files. It returns TRUE or FALSE. 
I have a list of `"1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt" "4.txt"   "final.csv""final1.csv"  "final2.csv" "GSM248238.CEL" "GSM248650.CEL" "GSM248651.CEL" "GSM248652.CEL" "GSM248653.CEL" "GSM248655.CEL" "GSM248659.CEL" "GSM248660.CEL" "GSM248661.CEL"`

Now if i am interested to check something like `c(".cel",".txt",".csv")`. I thought to try `grepl(c("*.cel$",".txt$",".csv$"), ignore.case=TRUE)`, it gives the extension of first(.cel). Other extension are also present, how to get all the extensions.

Comment: You can use `paste`, i.e. `grepl(paste('.cel$', '.txt$', .csv$', collapse='|'), yourfiles, ignore.case=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun Returns `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: The bar, `|`, operator is equivalent to `or` in R. `'*.cel$' or '*.txt$'` in regex is `'*.cel$ | *.txt$'`.

Comment: @akrun just needs a single quote before `.csv$'`

Comment: I didn't test it, but I think some variant of that should work, @plafort thanks a typo there

Comment: `"\\.(cel|txt|csv)$"` because `.` is a wildcard character.

Comment: I should have used `c`, i.e. `paste(c('.cel$', '.txt$', '.csv$'), collapse='|')`

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate but I can't find the question. :/ Basically, the pattern argument to the regular expression functions in R isn't vectorized, so you need to collapse it into a single regex pattern as akrun and Frank have done.

Comment: @plafort '.csv$' is not the case . not working either

Comment: If you are constructing your list from the file structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876813/using-r-to-list-all-files-with-a-specified-extension

Comment: @akrun Looking for a dupe :)

Comment: @Frank: David already marked this as a dupe.

Comment: @AlexA. Ah thanks. The page didn't alert me or update itself.

Comment: @Frank, Will U not post your solution

Comment: @AaghazHussain Because this question (or something very close to it) has been asked before, it is closed to new answers. Refresh the page and you'll see the so-called "duplicate" question linked in a yellow header. My solution in the comment will still be here for anyone who comes across your question later. Here's the help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: @Frank I already saw the duplicate mark. Thanks

Comment: @Frank I have a similar problem dealing with multiple extensions. i tried `"\\.(cel|txt|csv)$"` as per your comment above and it return `TRUE` if files with any of the extension are present, however i am interested to check if all the three files or more are present.How to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can post a new question. Answers may come pretty slowly on the weekend, though.