# Matching all the file extensions

Tags: r, file-extension

I have a vector of file extensions like `(.txt,.TXT,.csv,.xls)`, i tried `"\\.(TXT|txt|csv|xls)$"` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244199/is-there-multiple-match-doable-with-any-pattern-matching-function) 
which return `TRUE` if any of the extensions are present, however i am interested to return a `TRUE` if all the extensions are present in the vector otherwise `FALSE`. Thanks

Comment: i tried `all` but it returns `TRUE`   always  if any of the extension is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 v1 <- c('a1.txt', 'a2.TXT', 'a3.csv', 'a22.txt', 'a13.TXT', 'a23.txt')
 ext <- c('txt', 'TXT', 'csv', 'xls')
 all(ext %in% sub('.*\\.', '', v1) )
 #[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Still 4 mins to go :):)

Comment: If i need to check if `txt` or`TXT` and `csv` and `xls`, how can i do that

Comment: @Hashim Isn't that the condition in the question or do you need `any` in place of `all`?

Comment: @Hashim Based on the example showed, what do you want to return

Comment: i mean can i do  `ignore.case ` here with `all`

Comment: @Hashim If I use `all(grepl('.txt|.csv|.xls', v1,ignore.case=TRUE))`, I get `TRUE` for `v1`.  But note that `.xls` is not in `v1`.  So, do you want the result to be `FALSE`

Comment: I think it will give true if any of the three are present , but i want if all the three are present with both the cases

Comment: @Hashim Try `all(sapply(c('.txt', '.csv', '.xls'), function(x) any(grepl(x, v1, ignore.case=TRUE))))#
[1] FALSE`

Comment: I have an issue with v1 <- `c("GSE10952_Colon_cancer_cells_cell_line_nonorm_nobkgd_GEOarchive_Matrix.txt","GSE10952_Colon_cancer_cells_cell_line_nonorm_nobkgd_GEOarchive_Matrix1.txt")`, which gives `TRUE`, how its ??

Comment: I get `FALSE` for the example you provided. i.e `all(sapply(c('.txt', '.csv', '.xls'), function(x) any(grepl(x, v1, ignore.case=TRUE))))
#[1] FALSE`

Comment: I too got `FALSE` , what about the above two lines

Comment: @Hashim I am talking about the `v1 <- c("GSE10952_...`

Comment: can u plz try `all(sapply(c('.CEL', '.txt'), function(x) any(grepl(x, v1, ignore.case=TRUE))))`

Comment: @Hashim Now I understand the reason, you have `cell` inside the text which matched with `cel` and `.` is just any character.  Try `all(sapply(c('\\.CEL', '\\.txt'), function(x) any(grepl(x, v1, ignore.case=TRUE))))#
[1] FALSE` or make it more specific `all(sapply(c('\\.CEL$', '\\.txt$'), function(x) any(grepl(x, v1, ignore.case=TRUE))))
[1] FALSE`

Comment: Oh my bad !!, yes that is the reason, sorry for asking here.

Comment: @Hashim  It's okay, that question looked good and would have gained me some reputation points :-)