# Get summary / plot for a column out of a folder (~3000 csv files) in R

Tags: r, csv, plot, rstudio, summary

I'm a student from Germany. I want to create a summary (0.25 & 0.75 quantile, mean, min, max) and different plots for special columns (e.g. `Inflow` or `Low`).
The issue is that there is not only one .csv file, there are about 3200 files in that folder - different names (ISIN numbers of portfolios all starting with `DE000LS9xxx`).
After I looked through different platforms and this forum I tried different possibilities. My last try was to name every file 001.csv, 002.csv, etc. and use an answer out of this forum:

```
 directory <- setwd("~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata/")
 Inflowmean <- function(directory, Inflow, id = 1:3) {
 filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
 filenames <- paste(directory, filenames, sep=";", dec=",")
 ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
 df=ldply(ldf)
 summary(df[, Inflow], na.rm = TRUE)
 }
```

I really hope that you can help me, cause I'm new and just started to learn commands in RStudio - seems that I'm not able to handle it, also tried different tutorials and the help function in the program...
Thank you so much!

Comment: did you actually try to use the code you posted? it could be a solution, although I suspect that there are probably several other ways to do the same stuff... If you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: So, what is your question? Does the code above run? If not, what is the error? What specifically do you want help with?

Comment: the code doesn't run and there is no error notification showing up. It just shows the code in the console, but there is no summary for the testdata.
The help I need is how to get that code or any other code doing the thing that I need. I'm sorry to say it, but I'm a noob with R and not best in programming or understanding it

Answer (score 0):

from
[Using R to list all files with a specified extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876813/using-r-to-list-all-files-with-a-specified-extension)
and
[Opening all files in a folder, and applying a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function)

```
filenames <- list.files("~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
res <- lapply(ldf, summary)
```

Comment: if I try to get that code running, `it says Error in lapply(ldf, summary) : object 'ldf' not found` but in the `environment` windows it detects the files in the folder when I use `path="~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata"` instead of `temp`

Answer (score 0):

It is rather unclear what your question actually is, but there are a number of problems with your code:

- `directory <- setwd("~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata/")`: See `?setwd` - it returns the current directory **before** changing the working directory, not `~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata/`. You probably want

  ```
  directory <- "~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata/"
  setwd(directory)
  ```
- `filenames <- paste(directory, filenames, sep=";", dec=",")` -- this will create filenames like "~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata/;001.csv;,". You probably want the separator to be `/` or `.Platform$file.sep`. I don't know why you have `dec=","` but that will just paste it onto the end. Try `paste`ing a few things together to see what gives you file names that make sense for your data.
- Your `ldply` syntax is wrong: you probably want

  ```
  ldply(ldf, function (x) summary(x[, Inflow], na.rm=T))
  ```

See `?ldply` for more information. Also, to use `ldply`, you need `library(plyr)` somewhere. If you just want base R, you could try

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function (x) summary(x[, Inflow], na.rm=T)))
```

Where the `lapply` applies your function (`summary(x[, Inflow], na.rm=T)`) to each of your dataframes, and `do.call(rbind, ...)` just joins all the summaries together into a single dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for you fast answer! I tried to it your info into my dataset, but it doesn't work :/ Did I do it the right way?
The plyr package is installed 

  `directory <- "~/Desktop/Uni/paper/testdata/"
  setwd(directory)
  Inflowsummary <- function(directory, Inflow, id = 1:3) {
  filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
  filenames <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/", dec=",")
  ldf <- laply(filenames, read.csv)
  df=ldply(ldf, function (x) summary(x[, Inflow], na.rm=T))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function (x) summary(x[, Inflow], na.rm=T)))
  summary(df[, Inflow], na.rm = TRUE)
  }`

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does "it doesn't work" mean, and what specifically do you want to happen?