# Using R - How do I search for a file/folder on all drives (hard drives as well as USB drives)

Tags: r

Please help -  using R, how would I search for a specific file/folder on all drives (hard drives as well as attached USB drives)?

For example, I'm looking for a directory named "MyFiles", and it could be anywhere on my C:, or on my USB (E:). I'd like to know all the tree locations of the directory.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This sort of question has been asked (and answered) before (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876813/using-r-to-list-all-files-with-a-specified-extension?rq=1) If your question is different to these please consider expanding it.

Comment: The poster wants to search the entire tree whereas the link provided only searches the current directory.

Comment: @phil - thanks for your link - but I'd like to search all possible locations in the tree for a specific file, as g-grothendieck specified. I'll updated the question to make that clearer.

Comment: Do you want R to figure out what all the drives are for you? If not then just use the `recursive` parameter for `list.files()` with the drive as the path.

Comment: thanks @hrbrmstr - I actually do want R to figure out the drives, but I'm converging on a solution using `drives <- paste0(letters,":/")` and `list.dirs(drives)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Messed up a bit in the comment as I misread the thread (you need dirs). You can still do this with `list.files()` tho. I mocked up a directory structure looking for directories named "`data`" but also included a file named "`data`":

```
(pre <- list.files("/var/tmp/a", "data", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, include.dirs=TRUE))

## [1] "/var/tmp/a/data"   "/var/tmp/a/l/data" "/var/tmp/a/q/data"
```

(`/var/tmp/a/l/data` is actually just a file)

But, you only need/want directories, so if you have a fairly modern R install and the `purrr` package installed then you can do:

```
purrr::keep(pre, dir.exists)

## [1] "/var/tmp/a/data"   "/var/tmp/a/q/data"
```

Answer (score 7):

I see it's an old question, but now we can use the [`fs`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/01/fs-1.0.0/) package that according to the tidyverse blog and the package vignette "**provides a cross-platform, uniform interface to file system operations**" and "**smooth over some of the idiosyncrasies of file handling with base R functions**".

Here's how we can accomplish this task with `fs`:

```
fs::dir_ls(path = c("C:/", "E:/"), type = "directory", glob = "*MyFiles", recurse = TRUE)
```

There are a couple of added advantages to using this approach:

1. If we have a general sense of where this directory should be in the folder hierarchy, we can recurse upto a certain level instead of searching the entire tree. We just need to add the argument `recurse = #num_levels_to_recurse)` to the above code.
2. Also, if we want to list all directories except `MyFiles`, we can add the argument `invert = TRUE` to the above code.

These two options are not available in `list.files()` and `list.dirs()` functions of base R. Check out [this document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/vignettes/function-comparisons.html) for a thorough comparison between `fs` functions and base R functions for file system operations.