# How to exclude some files in the folder

Tags: r

I have some files in the directory and their extensions all same. I want list all files but later on would like to ignore some of the file names that contain certain strings. I tried `grepl` using this answer [using-r-to-list-all-files-with-a-specified-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876813/using-r-to-list-all-files-with-a-specified-extension).

For instance in this example I would like exclude the files which contains 'B' in it. So tried,

```
file_names <- c('AA','BA','KK','CB')
files <- paste0(file_names,'.txt')

Filter_files <- files[-grepl('.*B.txt|.B*.txt', files)]

Filter_files

 "BA.txt" "KK.txt" "CB.txt"
```

Interestingly only `AA.txt` excluded!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
file_names <- c('AA','BA','KK','CB')
files <- paste0(file_names,'.txt')

Filter_files <- files[!grepl('.*B.*\\.txt', files)]

Filter_files

## "AA.txt" "KK.txt"
```

These are the changes I made:

- Instead of `-`, the `grepl` is preceded by `!`, which negates the result of the `grepl` (i.e., the `TRUE` results become `FALSE` and viceversa).
- To capture all the Bs regardless of where they are located, I search for any character (that's what `.` indicates) appearing 0 or more times (indicated by the `*` sign). This way whether the B is at the beginning or the end of the filename it is equally captured.
- Since `.` has the special meaning of 'any character' in regex, to have a literal dot in the expression you have to escape it, thus `\\.` before the txt extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. could you little bit explain what the `'` and `\\\` and `*` means. I was using `*` only but really don't know what they are standing for ? In addition If I wanted to add another file names for exclude how can I implement them. Could you add these points to your solution too! Thanks.

Comment: I updated the post with my changes. Let me know if you have any further questions.