# List files that end with pattern and lack an extension

Tags: r, regex, path

I have a directory with multiple subdirectories that contain files.
The files themselves have no extension; however, each file has an additional header file with the extension `".hdr"`.

In R, I want to list all file names that contain the string `map_masked` and end with the pattern `"masked"`, but I only want the files without an extension (the ones that **end** with the pattern, not the header files).

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4876869/11611246), I tried to use the `$` sign to indicate the pattern should occur at the end of a line.

This is the code I used:

```
dir <- "/my/directory"

list.files(dir, pattern = "map_masked|masked$", recursive = TRUE)
```

The output, however, looks as follows:

```
[1] "subdirectory/something_map_masked_something_masked"
[2] "subdirectory/something_map_masked_something_masked.hdr"
etc.
```

Now, how do I tell R to exclude the files that have an `".hdr"` extension?
I am aware this could easily be done by applying a filter on the output, but I would rather like to know what is wrong with my code and understand why R behaves the way it does in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
list.files(dir, pattern = "map_masked.*masked$", recursive = TRUE)
```

It returns filepaths that contain `map_masked` and end with `masked` string.

*Details*:

- `map_masked` - a fixed string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `masked` - a `masked` substring
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hKZvp9/1).