# Connect to all SQLite databases in directory using purrr:: map

Tags: r, sqlite, purrr

I need to connect to multiple SQLite Databases in a directory.

Is there a way to do this elegantly using list.files and purrr:: map?
I would further like to map generic queries to the databases (Select * ...)

I'm looking forward to your answers!

So far I have this:

```
data.frame(
  files = list.files("./",pattern="*.sqlite") 
) |>
  mutate(
    dbs = map(.x=files,~dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),.x))) |>
  mutate(
    data = map(.x=dbs,~dbGetQuery(.x,"Select * from geometry_columns"))
  )
```

Is there a way to get the connections into the "connection environment" as well?

Comment: listing files by extension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4876869/16730940.  Now write out what you want to do (the generic queries) as a function that takes the db file name as an argument, then `lapply()` your function to the list.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code? What "connection environment" are you referring to? It's not clear what exactly the current problem is. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.