# How to import many .wav files in R?

Tags: r, wav

I'm starting with bioacoustics in R and my question is how to import all my .wav files into R?

There are more than 20,000 files and I can't import them one at a time. Can someone help me?

setwd("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Gravador 01")

a <- readWave("20231122_084200.WAV")
savewav(a)

playlist("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Gravador 01", sample = FALSE, loop = 1)

erro: '20230901_095102.wav' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using R to list all files with a specified extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876813/using-r-to-list-all-files-with-a-specified-extension)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to 'move' files from one directory to another rather than trying to bring all into a R session.  This is how I interpret your readWave; savewav. Where are the readWave(s) coming from, i.e. which directory?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is create a function that imports all the files at once. Here is the code:

```
import_file <- function(path){
  files <- list.files(path = path, 
                      pattern = ".wav$", full.names = TRUE)

  data <- purrr::map_df(files, ~tuneR::readWave(.x))

  return(data)
}

# Run the function
data <- import_file(path = "write the path to your files here")
```

Note that this function will import the data into a dataframe. Then you would need to reshape the data based on your needs.